# error when running executable file on UWSim

Tags: ros, uwsim

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The example code is including three files which are header file, member function file and main file. And the code is copied from the textbook.

```
I put the header file on the path:/home/gupta/catkin_ws_2/src/underwater_simulation/uwsim/include/uwsim. 
I put the member function file on the path /home/gupta/catkin_ws_2/src/underwater_simulation/uwsim/src. 
I put the main file on the path: /home/gupta/catkin_ws_2/src/underwater_simulation/underwater_vehicle_dynamics/src
```

Then I add something in the CMakeList.txt:

```
add_executable(mainstudent /home/gupta/catkin_ws_2/src/underwater_simulation/underwater_vehicle_dynamics
/src/mainstudent.cpp)

target_link_libraries(mainstudent uwsim ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${Boost_LIBRARIES} ${BULLET_LIBRARIES})

add_library(uwsim 
...
src/student.cpp
...
)
```

---

header file:

```
class Student
{
public:
    void display();
private:
    int num;
    char name[20];
    char sex;
};
```

---

function member file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "uwsim/student.h"
using namespace std;

void Student::display()
{
    cout<<"num="<<num<<endl;
    cout<<"name="<<name<<endl;
    cout<<"sex="<<sex<<endl;
}
```

---

main file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "uwsim/student.h"

int main()
{
    Student stud;
    stud.display();
    return 0;
}
```

---

There is no error when compiling the code. However, there is error when running the executable file on the terminal. And the error is shown below:

```
Loading SimulatedDevices plugin: 'DredgeTool_Factory'
Loading SimulatedDevices plugin: 'ForceSensor_Factory'
Loading SimulatedDevices plugin: 'SimDev_Echo_Factory'
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'pluginlib::LibraryUnloadException'
  what():  According to the loaded plugin descriptions the class ForceSensor_Factory with base class type uwsim::SimulatedDeviceFactory does not exist. Declared types are `enter code here`DredgeTool_Factory ForceSensor_Factory SimDev_Echo_Factory
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Any suggestion?  Thanks so much.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/235855/error-when-running-executable-file-on-uwsim/) by [ZYS](https://answers.ros.org/users/25674/zys/) on ROS Answers with karma: 108 on 2016-06-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-06-01**:
Please format your question properly: use the *Preformatted Text* button (with `101010` on it) for all code and console copy/pastes. Right now it's unreadable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Having a look at your code files, it seems you are mixing the files in different packages. I'm not sure if something like that is supposed to work but I think there is no need to do it. So why are you putting header and member files in one package (uwsim) and the main file  in a different one (underwater_vehicle_dynamics)?. Beyond that the CMakeLists is from uwsim package?, you shouldn't call a file from a different package in a CMakeList (first two lines). Finally if student classes do not work with uwsim core, as far as I can see they do not include a single file from it, there is no need to add them to the same library, I would create a new one for them or even a new package for them and left unmodified the uwsim package.

Anyway code from the new files is simple enough to work, problem is in the way you are building them.

---

Originally posted by [Javier Perez](https://answers.ros.org/users/3430/javier-perez/) with karma: 486 on 2016-06-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0